# Listings, Cleverref, and Appendix: Weird Alignment

Tags: spacing, listings, vertical-alignment, appendices, cleveref

I'm using the packages `listings` and `cleverref` in my thesis. When I put a listing in the appendix, however, it seems to be somehow indented:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{cleveref}  % <-- remove me!

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
a
a
a
\end{lstlisting}

\appendix
\noindent\rule{2cm}{.2mm}
\begin{lstlisting}
a
a
a
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Here's the result:

[image: result]

Removing the `\usepackage{cleverref}` fixes the problem.

This looks especially ugly since in my real document I'm framing the listings with `mdframed`: the frame is in the correct position, making the left margin seem huge.

Comment: This is surely a spurious space in `cleveref.sty`; hunting it down is not easy.

Comment: If I add `\lstset{xleftmargin=-3.33333pt}` before the second listing, the result is as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a missing `%` on line 196 of `cleverref.sty`

```
                \csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}
```

should be

```
                \csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: Spot on, thanks! On a side note: how do you debug such a problem? I do know `normal' programming languages and the use of debuggers, but with LaTeX all I know is trial and error ;).

Comment: @rainer http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11413280#11413280  http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11413296#11413296 :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Not to forget http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11410269#11410269 `;-)`

Comment: Thanks for the info! Not quite as systematic as I expected, but at least simple enough :).

Comment: @rainer If I had not been so sure that it was a missing % I'd have added `\tracingnall` and then stepped through the two listings in emacs to see where the space was added. But it was late and the initial instant edit of adding % to every `}` fixed the problem, the binary chop was just to cut down the size of the above answer

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is already fixed in the latest cleveref version at http://www.dr-qubit.org/latex.php#cleveref (not yet on CTAN).

Comment: Yes, it is fixed in 0.18.10. I accepted David's answer however since he debugged the problem for me.

Comment: That's a shame. I don't care about the SE credit, or reputation, or whatever it's called. But the correct solution to any bug is not to immediately leap in and hack the code, but rather to *first* check if it's already been fixed in a newer upstream release. And if it's not already fixed, *report* it *upstream*, not (only) on SE.The bug you reported had already been fixed before you posted your question. Accepting David's otherwise admirable answer misses a valuable opportunity to encourage people to check for upstream bug-fixes before posting to tex.SE.